# Better way to access beanFactory in Spring3 Web App

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to find a better way to access beanFactory in Spring3 Web App.  Right now I setup a config.xml file with all my services that my system is going to use and in the controller I ad a line of code like:

```
private static XmlBeanFactory beanFactory = new XmlBeanFactory(new ClassPathResource("config.xml"));
```

in each controller..  Does anyone know of any better way to do this?

Comment: What technology do you use for controllers?

Comment: @Stuttering John, like GriffeyDog says, you should not be using the beanfactory/application context to get reference to the beans, you should be expecting the dependent beans to be injected into your controllers. If you absolutely need access to the beanfactory, you can implement the org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Spring MVC, presumably you've defined a servlet in web.xml to handle the requests, like:

```
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>dispatcher</display-name>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

In which case you should have a Spring config file named something like dispatcher-servlet.xml in your web-inf directory. Put your bean definitions in there and they will get defined and be available when the servlet starts up.

EDIT:

Importing one bean configuation file into another, from section 3.2.2.1 of the Spring reference:

```
<beans>

    <import resource="services.xml"/>
    <import resource="resources/messageSource.xml"/>
    <import resource="/resources/themeSource.xml"/>

    <bean id="bean1" class="..."/>
    <bean id="bean2" class="..."/>

</beans>
```

Autowiring bean example in controller:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
  @Autowired
  private MyBeanClass myBeanName;
  ...
}
```

Comment: are you saying I should move all my beans from config.xml into the Dispatacher.xml and then how do I access the factory from the controllors

Comment: You can <import> your config.xml into dispatcher-servlet.xml instead of moving the definitions, if you want. If your controllers are annotated with the controller annotation, then you can use the autowire annotation inside the controllers to inject your beans.

Comment: do you have a example of both?

Comment: I am getting this error now: SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'os400dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class

Comment: That's a different issue. You may be missing the JDBC jar on your classpath.

Comment: Updated my answer with examples.